# How to write a trait that has a method returning a reference and implement it correctly?

Tags: rust

I want to write a trait that has a method like `foo(&self) -> &T` and implement it for a concrete type rather than a reference. Here is what I've tried, but I can not get it to work:

```
trait GetRef<'a> {
    fn get(&self) -> &'a u8;
}

// U8Ref works fine
struct U8Ref<'a> {
    data: &'a u8
}

impl<'a> GetRef<'a> for U8Ref<'a> {
    fn get(&self) -> &'a u8 {
        self.data
    }
}

struct U80 { data: u8 }
struct U81 { data: u8 }
struct U82 { data: u8 }
struct U83 { data: u8 }

// works, but is not exactly what I want (API changes, and does not work on
// &mut U80, see main() below)
impl<'a> GetRef<'a> for &'a U80 {
    fn get(&self) -> &'a u8 {
        &self.data
    }
}

impl<'a> GetRef<'a> for U81 {
    fn get(&self) -> &'a u8 {
        // E0495: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter
        // in generic type due to conflicting requirements
        &self.data
    }
}

impl<'a> GetRef<'a> for U82 {
    //E0308: lifetime mismatch
    fn get(&'a self) -> &'a u8 {
        &self.data
    }
}

impl<'a> GetRef<'a> for &'a mut U83 {
    fn get(&self) -> &'a u8 {
        // again E0495
        &self.data
    }
}

fn main() {
    let u0 = U80 {data :0};

    // works
    (&u0).get();

    // no method named `get` found for type `U80` in the current scope
    u0.get();

    // no method named `get` found for type `&mut U80` in the current scope
    (&mut u0).get();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementations of your trait need to constrain the lifetimes involved.  For your `U8Ref` case the lifetime will outlive `self`, but in the `U80` and similar cases they will be equal.

The trait needs to have both lifetimes as inputs to be able to express this, so let's add the `self` lifetime as `'s`:

```
trait GetRef<'a, 's> {
    fn get(&'s self) -> &'a u8;
}
```

Now those are explicit, we can write the `impl`s.  First, for the one which holds a reference:

```
struct U8Ref<'a> {
    data: &'a u8
}

// Straightforward; we can separate the self and return reference lifetimes.
impl<'a, 's> GetRef<'a, 's> for U8Ref<'a> {
    fn get(&'s self) -> &'a u8 {
        self.data
    }
}
```

And now for the harder case before, we can explicitly tell the compiler the lifetimes are the same:

```
struct U80 { data: u8 }

// The impl is only valid when &self has the same lifetime as the &u8 returned.
impl<'a> GetRef<'a, 'a> for U80 {
    fn get(&'a self) -> &'a u8 {
        &self.data
    }
}
```

And use it to check it compiles:

```
fn main() {
    let mut u0 = U80 {data :0};
    let uval: u8 = 7;
    let ur0 = U8Ref { data: &uval };

    ur0.get();

    (&u0).get();

    u0.get();

    (&mut u0).get();
    {
        // Check that it works when U8Ref's reference outlives itself.
        let v = 0u8;
        let u: &u8;
        {
            let r = U8Ref { data: &v };
            u = r.get();
        }
        println!("{}", u);
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=669c31e0495a7b51699ef0509f246a6b&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Comment: Thanks for your answer which solves my original problem. But can you help me with why adding a `mut` makes it not working again ... [Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=faaf3de7c6c0068c7804178b1160b0e6&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Comment: Adding &mut where? Probably worth asking in a new question.

Comment: see my [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=faaf3de7c6c0068c7804178b1160b0e6&version=stable&backtrace=0); if this is not immediately solvable, I would ask a new question.

Comment: @jiakai Is [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4c890310ecc8f09c6b363dc6fa284d30&version=nightly&backtrace=0) what you're trying to do?

Comment: @not-important not exactly; the point is that a `U8MutRef` may hold a reference with longer lifetime than itself, so we have to write `impl<'a, 's> GetRef<'a, 's> for U8MutRef<'a>` rather than `impl<'a> GetRef<'a, 'a> for U8MutRef<'a> `, and it causes compile error in your code too.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should specify that `&self` has the same lifetime as the returned value (both in trait in the implementation). Otherwise, the compiler correctly tells you that the value may not live long enough.

Second, you should `impl` the trait for the type itself, not for a reference to the type. If you write `impl Trait for &'a U80`, `&self` inside that `impl` will have type `&&U80`, which is not what you want. Implementing the trait for `U80` will make the trait method available for `U80`, `&U80` and `&mut U80` simultaneously because the trait methods receives `&self`.

```
trait GetRef<'a> {
    fn get(&'a self) -> &'a u8;
}

struct U8Ref<'a> {
    data: &'a u8
}

impl<'a> GetRef<'a> for U8Ref<'a> {
    fn get(&self) -> &'a u8 {
        self.data
    }
}

struct U80 { data: u8 }

impl<'a> GetRef<'a> for U80 {
    fn get(&'a self) -> &'a u8 {
        &self.data
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut u0 = U80 {data :0};
    (&u0).get();
    u0.get();
    (&mut u0).get();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply:) However I can not *specify that `&self` has the same lifetime as the returned value*, since `U8Ref` may actually hold something that outlives itself.

Comment: For example, I hope something like this can work: 

`fn main() {
    let v = 0u8;
    let u: &u8;
    {
        let r = U8Ref { data: &v };
        u = r.get();
    }
`